# Synchronize from iPhone to Mac

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

The situation: My HDD crashed, I didn't have any backups. I get a new SSD. I had my iPhone synced with the old HDD as usual.

The problem: How can I sync Apps/Music/Podcasts from my iPhone (where everything is normal) **back** to my Mac (where iTunes is clean)?

If I just check the boxes for synchronisation in the "new" iTunes, it will override the data on my iPhone.

The solution: **?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily take a backup of your iPhone on your new Mac.

[image]

To transfer your media to your new iTunes, follow [this tutorial](http://evolver.fm/2011/02/28/how-to-switch-an-old-iphone-to-a-new-computer/) in order to do so. If I understand your question correctly, this is what you need.

Comment: If I understand correctly, he cannot take an old backup since the HDD crashed. Now he wants to sync his iPhone to new iTunes setup (without losing all his data).

Comment: Yes, he has to connect his iPhone to his new iTunes in which he will be able to take a backup from, by right-clicking the iPhone in iTunes and selecting `Back Up`

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer purchased apps or just re-download the latest versions from the App store.  For music files on stock OS iOS devices, you may need to find a backup of your downloads somewhere (Time Machine, et.al.).