# Sync/transfer TV Shows and Movies from iPhone to Mac?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I have just updated my Mac to Lion and started using iCloud. Next thing I want to do is update my phone to iOS 5, but I want to backup all my purchased TV Shows first.
Some of them are purchased on my iPhone and I would like to transfer them to my Mac.

I connected my iPhone to my Mac, clicked on my iPhone in the iTunes submenu **Devices** and when I click on **TV Shows**, I can't click on anything in there, except for **Sync TV Shows**. But when I click on that I get the message:

> "Are you sure you want to sync TV shows? All existing songs, movies
>   and TV shows on the iPhone will be removed and replaced with TV shows
>   from your iTunes library."

How can I transfer all my TV Shows and Movies to my Mac without a hassle?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/54240/11135) has instructions which should be having the effect you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply click on purchased in the itunes store and redownload all of your purchases directly to your computer.